# Exit function after if

Tags: python, if-statement, exit

This maybe a stupid question, but I don't kow how to exit the function below after if statement. This code is written in python

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target:
        print("sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target))
        print("True")
        return

    if s > target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])

def main():
    print(subset_sum([10, 7, 6, 3], 13))

main()
```

The output is

```
sum([10, 3])=13
True
sum([7, 6])=13
True
None
```

What I need is when sum([10,3)]==13, the function will print

```
sum([10, 3])=13
True
```

and then end.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the return value of the function. Your function returns `None` (the default return value), so that is what is printed.

Drop the `print()` function call, just call the function and leave it at that:

```
def main():
    subset_sum([10, 7, 6, 3], 13)
```

Next, your recursive function continues to search for additional solutions, because you don't flag when a solution has been found.

You could return `True` when you have found a solution, then stop all further searches when a recursive call is true:

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=None):
    partial = partial or []
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target:
        print("sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target))
        print("True")
        return True

    if s > target:
        return False # if we reach the number why bother to continue
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
        if subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n]):
            # solution found, stop searching
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: I'm still getting 
    sum([10, 3])=13
     True
     sum([7, 6])=13
     True

Comment: @K.U: added a solution; stop searching when a recursive call returns `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is just returning, which means it returns `None`. This is a problem when you're calling the function recursively, because the parent doesn't know whether it should continue recursing or not.

You should instead return a value that tells the parent call whether or not it should return or continue.